# Once edited a EDT in AX2012, can't change it

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have question.

I am programming a example Project.

I have a `EDT` called `Joining` and this `EDT` is of type `Date`.

I did put it in my table `employment` and in my form `employment`.

Now I want to have this field, that when entry one date for a dataset that I can never edit it again. 
How do I do that ? 
Do I have to write Code ?I guess.

With Kind regards

Khashayar

Answer (score 4):

On your table `Employment`, select the field and set the `AllowEdit=No` and leave the `AllowEditOnCreate=Yes`.

This will let users enter the date when they're creating the record, but not edit after.

You can **not** set this at the `EDT` level.

[image]